# I accidentally put the wrong batch in the fridge

Tags: beer, bottling, brewing

I bottle multiple batches every other weekend. I accidentally grabbed a wrong batch that was bottled with chico only a couple days before and put it into the fridge. I had not noticed until 2 weekes later. My question is - can I still pull this back out to finish carbing? or did I make an expensive bread starter?

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine, I would think, since it's the yeast that does the carbing in bottle conditioning. Yeast is stored in the fridge routinely before it's woken up, I just wouldn't want to give it any sudden temp changes. Might take a little longer to get it where you want it.

I routinely experience continued fermentation in beers that I keg & put in the kegerator because I'm just too impatient, too.

Here's someone who had a similar question just to show I'm not completely FOS: https://www.homebrewtalk.com/forum/threads/refrigerated-too-early-fermentation-recoverable.60403/